# Run time Permission popup click issue in Marshmallow Updated devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

I integrated Android Runtime Permission for `READ PHONE STATE` for Marshmallow devices. This implementation is working fine and the popup is showing in my application with allow/deny option.

I can click the allow/ deny button for normal marshmallow devices. But in the case of updated android devices(From Lollipop to Marshmallow), the allow button click is not working initial time. This issue is tested and reproduced in Nexus 5 and Nexus 7. Is anything we need to create additional for updated OS? Or is it a Marshmallow issue?

Please check the complete code:

```
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 101;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
   if(mActivity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                if (this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                                    showExplanationDialog(mActivity, getString(R.string.dialog_message_phone_state));
                                } else {
                                    this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                                }
                            } else {
                                handleLoginAPI();
                            }
                        } else {
                            handleLoginAPI();
                        }

     private void handleLoginAPI() {
      if (super.isNetworkConnectionAvailable(mActivity)) {
        // Api Call from here.. 
      }else{
        // No Nw Connection.
      }

    }

    @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        handleLoginAPI();
                    } else if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        if (this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                            showExplanationDialog(mActivity, getString(R.string.dialog_message_phone_state));
                        }
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are asking for permission and the activityResult method

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question. But the issue is only in updates OS?.

Comment: No, not necessarily, I myself use updated OS phone, it works fine for me. May be some implementation issues.

Comment: Please check my implemenation

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Android OS update issue. The issue is reported in Nexus device. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213120. The issue can be reproducible in other android native application as like Google map, Gmail etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` before requesting the permission. That call is intended to be made after the user has rejected the request, usually in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method. If your app needs to explain why it needs a permission before it asks for it, the app's internal logic needs to decide that.

Comment: I am following the android developer console sample code. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html. You have any updated code. Please share if possible.

Comment: Was the app previously installed (before the upgrade)? If so, the permission will have been automatically granted. If not, then it's supposed to be like a (new) Marshmallow device. However, if the permission has never been requested (and rejected) then `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` will most likely return `false`. I've had the most reliable results internally tracking whether the first use has been "explained" and only rely on "show rationale" if the permission is rejected by the user. It will only return `true` if rejected and the user did not choose to supress future requests.

Comment: If interested, there is an open source helper library which makes this easier to deal with: https://github.com/hiqes/andele

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My application installed after the OS update. I will try with this library and update you soon.

Comment: This is an Android OS update issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213120. Please check the link. This issue reported in nexus device. One more thing I notice that the issue is happening in all Android native applications (Map, Gmail etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void setCheck()
    {
        int hasWriteContactsPermission = 0;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
                    showLocationRationleDalog();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            } else {
                handleLoginAPI();
            }
        } else {
            handleLoginAPI();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length == 1
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    handleLoginAPI();
                } else {
                    Log.i("Permission denied");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Any difference with my implementation?